# iphoneアプリのiPadへの対応　リジェクト2.10

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

先日提出したiPhoneアプリがリジェクトされました。
要因の一つが2.10のiPadへも対応しなければならないということを知らなかったことです。
そこで困っていることが二つあります。

一応iPadでも動けばいいとのことなのでDeploymentInfoのDevicesをユニバーサルにしてiOSシュミレータで実行したところ、画面内で全画面に対応しているところと、大きさがiPadに対応しておらず左上に固まったようになっているところとでバラバラになってしまいました。一応動作は問題ないのですが、これで提出しても問題ないでしょうか。

また A 76x76 app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later
というエラーが出ているのですが、76×76のアイコンを置いても消えません。
これはどこにアイコンを設定すればよいのいでしょうか。

初めての審査でよくわからないことが多く困っています。
どなたか、わかる方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

Appleからのメッセージの中に2.10とは別に、具体的な対処方法や問題箇所（iPadだとある画面でクラッシュするなど）は含まれていませんでしたか？

ユニバーサル対応をしろという事ではなく、iPad上でiPhoneアプリとして問題なく動作すれば良いはずです。
シミュレーターでも良いので一度iPadで実行して動作テストしてみてください。
（たしかiPad上では320x480ポイントで動作したと記憶していますので、
　その画面サイズで動作することが最低限求められます。）

Comment: 親切な回答ありがとうございます。
特に、画面の下の方が切れているとスクリーンショット付きで送られてきました。なので縦に短くなってしまっているんでと思います。これの直し方がわかりません。横は大丈夫なのですが...
iPadでiPhoneアプリとして動作できればいいとは、iPadで実行したときに余白が黒くなっていて使えればいいということですかね。

Comment: iPhoneはそもそも以下のように製品によって幅や高さが違いますが、そこは問題なく動作していますでしょうか？

iPhone4s → 320 x 480 ポイント
iPhone5/5s → 320 x 568 ポイント
iPhone6 → 375 x 667 ポイント
iPhone6Plus → 414 x 736 ポイント

繰り返しになりますが、iPad上でiPhoneアプリを動作させた場合はiPhone4Sと同等の320 x 480 ポイントで動作します（2倍表示される事もあります）。

※この時、余白は黒くなりますが、そういう仕様です。

お話を聞いている限りではiPhone4sのサイズで正しく動作していない（下の方が切れている）のではないかと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。
（シミュレーターで実行してみてください）

直し方につきましては、アプリケーションの作り方によるとしか言えませんが、
autolayoutを使っているようでしたら、そちらの解説サイトを見て頂ければ良いかと思いますし、
仮にコードでUIを配置しているようでしたら、例えば高さが568ポイントというハードコーディングを止めて、UIScreenクラスなどからディスプレイサイズを取得して算出するなどといった方法が考えられます。

Comment: iPhone4sのシュミレータで実行してみたところ、iPadと同様ちゃんと表示されていませんでした。しっかりとした確認を怠っていました。また、iPadの大きさがiPhone4sと同じだということも知りませんでした。iPhone4sで正しく表示されるよう直したいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

ユニバーサルとiphone appとは、違いますよ。

iphone appとは、iPad の上では、iPhone emulatorの上で動くもの。

ユニバーサルは、iPhoneとiPadの両対応のもので、iPadの上では、ネーティブな画面サイズでレイアウト崩れなどは、おきては、ダメです。

iPadで、App Storeにいくと、iPhoneとiPadで、Appの種類を選べれますが、iPadと選んだ場合は、iPhone Appは、フィルターされて、選択対象になりません。iPhone Appと選べば、ダウンロード出来ますが。

今回は、ユニバーサル対応できてないようなので、deployment deviceは、iPhoneにしたほうがいいのでは。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
そのようですね、今回はiPhone用のアプリなのでユニバーサル化はしないでいこうと思います。
deployment deviceをiPhoneにした場合、iPadのiOSシュミレータで動作させると画面の下の一部分が切れて全て表示されないのですがこれはどうすれば全て表示されるのでしょうか...ここがAppleから注意されました。

Comment: universal appは、iPadの上のiPhone simulatorで動きません。iPadの生の画面で動きます。だから、Appleの指摘がそうであるという記述は、おかしいですね。